# How to Validate Phone Number Field to accept only numbers and maximum 12 digits?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

I am doing validation for 10 digit Indian phone numbers (coding below). I am accepting digits only. What I can't seem to figure out is how to throw an error so that if the number entered begins with text or special characters and also not allow more than 12 Digits.
Or either trunacte numbers to 12 digits if user enters more than 12 digits.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="phoneregularExpression" runat="server" ErrorMessage="MoreThan10" EnableClientScript="false"
ControlToValidate="txtphone" Display="Static" Text="Please enter atleast 10 digits" ValidationExpression="^([0-9\(\)\/\+ \-]*)$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this i set max length to 12 to TextBox and Validator and validated it on regularexpression and tried it

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt" MaxLength="12"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
        ErrorMessage="Error" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txt"
        ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{12}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 7):

This Regex will make sure there is 10, but allow not more than 12:

```
^([0-9]{10,12})$
```

Here is a [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/sG1qP1) to prove it.

This one will allow 10 or 12 **only**, and an 11 digit one will fail.

```
^([0-9]{10}|[0-9]{12})$
```

Here is a [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/tE5xQ4) to prove it.

This one will allow 1 to 12 digits:

```
^([0-9]{1,12})$
```

Now, you've set `EnableClientScript` to false here. Which means there won't be any JavaScript validating it client-side. However, you need to make sure you call `this.Validate()` to force validation on the page **before** attempting to check if the validator `IsValid`.

Comment: @YasmeenAnsari, you call it. It's a [base method on the `Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ke7bxeh.aspx) class. So, in the code-behind for this ASPX page call `this.Validate();` in say the button click that tries to save data. Then all you have to do is check the [`IsValid` property of the `Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid.aspx) and if it's not valid, don't save, and post back so that the error message can be seen.

Comment: @YasmeenAnsari, it's up to you to **not run the save code.** It's not going to happen automatically. Further, the first Regex allows 10-12 digit numbers the second allows 10 **or** 12 digit numbers. *You said in your question that they needed to be 10 and no more than 12.* So yes, anything less than 10 is an error.

Comment: @YasmeenAnsari, if you just weren't clear in the question and meant that it can be 1 to 12 digits then I've edited my answer to give you a Regex that will allow between 1 and 12 digits, but if it's 0 digits it would throw an error too so if you need that then change the `1` to a `0` so it's `0,12` instead.

Comment: @ The Solution,_thanks for help_,your regex worked out correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1)maximum limit = 12

```
ValidationExpression="\d{0,12}"
```

2)require length = 12 but not limit

```
ValidationExpression="\d{12}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression

```
^[0-9]{12}$
```